# Understanding the difference between some grammatical points

Tags: grammar

> I've learned more from you than I could've from anyone else.

> I've learned more from you than I could from anyone else.

> I learned more from you than I could've from anyone else.

> I learned more from you than I could from anyone else.

Are there any differences between these? Do they have different meanings and use cases?

Comment: I'm inclined to parse the second example *(I've learned more from you than I could from anyone else)* as featuring "deleted predictably repeated elements" - specifically (discarding the contraction for clarity)  *I **have learned** more from you than I could **have learned** from anyone else.*

Comment: In principle, the implication of *...more than I could **learn / have learned** from anyone else* might be that ***learn*** implies I did actually ***try*** to learn from others, whereas the "more distant / hypothetical" alternative ***have learned*** might tend to imply ***if** I had tried to learn from others - but in fact I didn't do that anyway*. I know you didn't ask about exactly that either, but it might help you see what *kind* of distinctions could in principle be made. In practice though, I doubt many native speakers would either say or understand any such distinction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for the reply. So, in grammatical terms, would the first and second sentence sound correct (About the `discarding for clarity` part)? Oh, I see how that would possibly change the meaning if we don't know the meaning what we're talking about. The `could've` one might have a meaning like: `I didn't try to learn from others but even if I had tried, I wouldn't be able to learn as much as I did from you.`, right? In general, they all seem grammatically correct, or one might seem odd?

Comment: I personally would be inclined to interpret #2 and #4 as more strongly implying that the speaker *did in fact* learn (or try to learn) from others. And if ***I*** was the speaker, I'd probably only use those forms if I either *had* made such efforts, or at least wished to give the *impression* that I had. But frankly, I'm not convinced most (or even *many*) others would see things the same way. For most people in most contexts they're probably all equivalent.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Understood! I'll try to use `2` and `4`'s structures more but thanks for letting me know that it's mostly about the person's take on the sentence and they're all grammatically correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Learnt* is a spelling variant of *learned.* Grammarly claims that it is more common in the UK, but [this](https://proofreadmyessay.co.uk/writing-tips/word-choice-learned-vs-learnt/) disagrees.

Comment: Hello! Please read my sentences again. This isn't my question.

Comment: The point wasn't with `learned/learnt` so I deleted it...

Comment: Well, you didn't make it clear! I would say the first and last were the most idiomatic - or, for the last one, _than I did from anyone else_.

Comment: My bad. I should've made things clear at first. In grammatical terms, are they all correct? Also, do they convey different meanings from your perspective or they have the same message?

Comment: What FumbleFingers said. _Than I could_ implies that you were taught by other people too, _than I could have_ implies that you didn't study with other people and are guessing how it would have been.

Comment: Thank you for your time!